# i am making a django website with multiple forms also used foregin key ValueEror :The view Capp.views.InsertProduct didn't return anHttpResponseobject

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

i am making a django website with multiple forms also used foregin key(user_id) to link one form with other in the database but at the last i get value error the error is:Exception Type:  ValueError
Exception Value:
The view Capp.views.InsertProduct didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None insteated ,
the following is view.py file code(not complete code but only where error can lie)[models.py part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWZhp.png)

```
def InsertProduct(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('user_id') and request.POST.get('pname') and request.POST.get('pcategory') and request.POST.get('pdetails') and request.POST.get('foundedin') and request.POST.get('orderoftest') and request.POST.get('t1') and request.POST.get('t2') and request.POST.get('t3') and request.POST.get('f1') and request.POST.get('f2') and request.POST.get('f3') and request.POST.get('f4') and request.POST.get('f5'):
            saveproduct = ProInsert()
            saveproduct.user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
            saveproduct.pname = request.POST.get('pname')
            saveproduct.pcategory = request.POST.get('pcategory')
            saveproduct.pdetails = request.POST.get('pdetails')
            saveproduct.foundedin = request.POST.get('foundedin')
            saveproduct.orderoftest = request.POST.get('orderoftest')
            saveproduct.t1 = request.POST.get('t1')
            saveproduct.t2 = request.POST.get('t2')
            saveproduct.t3 = request.POST.get('t3')
            saveproduct.f1 = request.POST.get('f1')
            saveproduct.f2 = request.POST.get('f2')
            saveproduct.f3 = request.POST.get('f3')
            saveproduct.f4 = request.POST.get('f4')
            saveproduct.f5 = request.POST.get('f5')

            checkpname = ProInsert.objects.filter(
                pname=saveproduct.pname).first()
             return render(request, 'product_details.html')#here I had add what u said sir

            if checkpname:
                msgpname = messages.success(request, 'The user with Product Name ' +
                                            request.POST['pname']+' already exist...!')

                return render(request, 'product_details.html', {'msgpname': msgpname})
            saveproduct.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Product Added..!')

            return render(request, 'product_details.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'product_details.html')
```

Comment: There is no return in case second if condition fails..just check each case and corresponding return statement or make a default return HttpResponse object.

Comment: sir i am very new to django can u plz tell what can I return there ,or just add in code with comment to explain it and I c an see a return statement for the second if so can u plz suggest what can I return below which line

Comment: That depends on your implementation logic what you want to do if any of data from post request is not there  if request.POST.get('user_id') and request.POST.get('pname')......but for simple scenario you can return same page again by  
  return render(request, 'product_details.html').

Comment: sir i had return (request, 'product_details.html') these but again I am getting the same error I alsoedit the same in the question with a comment

Comment: `if request.POST.get('user_id') and request.POST....`--- this long `if` statement, if not satisfied, will cause your view to return nothing

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it wrong I have update your code and commented the part i was telling you.

```
def InsertProduct(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('user_id') and request.POST.get('pname') and request.POST.get('pcategory') and request.POST.get('pdetails') and request.POST.get('foundedin') and request.POST.get('orderoftest') and request.POST.get('t1') and request.POST.get('t2') and request.POST.get('t3') and request.POST.get('f1') and request.POST.get('f2') and request.POST.get('f3') and request.POST.get('f4') and request.POST.get('f5'):
            saveproduct = ProInsert()
            saveproduct.user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
            saveproduct.pname = request.POST.get('pname')
            saveproduct.pcategory = request.POST.get('pcategory')
            saveproduct.pdetails = request.POST.get('pdetails')
            saveproduct.foundedin = request.POST.get('foundedin')
            saveproduct.orderoftest = request.POST.get('orderoftest')
            saveproduct.t1 = request.POST.get('t1')
            saveproduct.t2 = request.POST.get('t2')
            saveproduct.t3 = request.POST.get('t3')
            saveproduct.f1 = request.POST.get('f1')
            saveproduct.f2 = request.POST.get('f2')
            saveproduct.f3 = request.POST.get('f3')
            saveproduct.f4 = request.POST.get('f4')
            saveproduct.f5 = request.POST.get('f5')

            checkpname = ProInsert.objects.filter(
                pname=saveproduct.pname).first()
            # return render(request, 'product_details.html')# NO need to add here as code below will be dead in this case.
            if checkpname:
                msgpname = messages.success(request, 'The user with Product Name ' +
                                            request.POST['pname']+' already exist...!')
                return render(request, 'product_details.html', {'msgpname': msgpname})
            saveproduct.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Product Added..!')
            return render(request, 'product_details.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'product_details.html')# What i meant was to add it here 
    else:
        return render(request, 'product_details.html')
```

Comment: sir i had copy and paste ur code also marked proper indentations  but still I am getting the same error

Comment: sir we can solve this on google meet (I had send u follow request on linkdin)meet.google.com/swr-mhdp-oxp

Comment: no need sir i am done i get it there was a spelling mistake in models .py

Comment: Glad you debugged it yourself :)